# How to perform sequence classification with a neural network?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, classification

Basically, I'm looking for any way to use Pytorch neural networks to classify sequences of numbers. After doing some searching, it seems like LSTM layers are the way to go, but all the examples I've found online involve classification of sequences of text, not numbers. I'm wondering if there are any examples of neural networks that can classify sequences of numbers.

Comment: Text is usually converted in numerical embeddings (one-hot, or learned ones) -> sequences of numbers. I suggest you read the PyTorch tutorial you mentioned since they can be applied to your problem as well.